# Заменить на заданный идентификатор значение k -го по порядку элемента списка

Tags: c, список

Этот код на деле удаляет количество первых элементов списка, которое я ввожу вместо переменной k, ввожу цифру 5 удаляет 5 первых элементов списка. Нужно сделать так, чтобы K-ый элемент списка можно было заменить на заданный с клавиатуры элемент.

А вот  сама задача:

> Дан список идентификаторов. Длина каждого идентификатора не более 8 символов. Идентификаторы в списке расположены в лексикографическом порядке. Составить функцию (подпрограмму) для следующей операции: заменить на заданный идентификатор значение k -го по порядку элемента списка...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAXDL 9

struct EL_SP {
    char id[MAXDL];
    struct EL_SP *sled;
};
void DelFirstK(struct EL_SP *p, unsigned k1)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= k1; i++) {
        struct EL_SP *pt;
        pt = p;
        p = p->sled;
        pt->sled = p->sled;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAXDL; i++)
            pt->id[i] = p->id[i];
        p = pt;
    }
}

void Vkl(struct EL_SP **p, char t_id[])
{
    struct EL_SP *pt, *k, *j;
    pt = (struct EL_SP *) malloc(sizeof(struct EL_SP));
    strcpy(pt->id, t_id);
    if (*p == NULL || strcmp(pt->id, (*p)->id) < 0) {
        pt->sled = *p;
        *p = pt;
    } else {
        k = *p;
        while (k != NULL && strcmp(pt->id, k->id) >= 0) {
            j = k;
            k = k->sled;
        }

        j->sled = pt;
        pt->sled = k;
    }
}

void PechSp(struct EL_SP *p)
{
    struct EL_SP *i;
    printf("nRezyltat:n");
    for (i = p; i != NULL; i = i->sled)
        puts(i->id);
}

void main(void)
{
    struct EL_SP *p;
    unsigned n;
    unsigned i;
    unsigned k;
    char t_id[MAXDL];
    printf("nVvedite chislo identifikatorovn n=");
    scanf("%U", &n);
    getchar();
    p = NULL;
    printf("Vvedite identifikatory");
    printf("(posle kazhdogo nazhimajte klavishu <Enter>)n");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        gets(t_id);
        Vkl(&p, t_id);
    }
    PechSp(p);

    printf("nKakou ydalit?:n");
    scanf("%d", &k);

    DelFirstK(p, k);

    printf("nAfter clear:n");

    PechSp(p);
    printf("nDlja zavershenija nazhmite ljubuju klavishun");
    getch();
}
```

Простите что выкладываю свое задание по учебе, но я в безвыходной ситуации, не могу, вернее просто не умею, читал лекции, методичку, никак не получается, надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: Пожалуйста отформатируйте код, чтоб было легко и приятно читать его. http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=42454874

Comment: Например, здесь: [indentcode.net](http://indentcode.net/).

Comment: @coddddder, что у Вас не получается после ответа @margosh ? 

Если все получилось, то примите ответ и закойте свойй вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю задание, то наверно можно как-то так :

```
int replase (struct EL_SP *p, int k, char* str) 
{
  struct EL_SP *pt;
  int i;
  pt = p;
  for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
  {
    if(pt->sled != NULL)
      pt = pt->sled;
    else {
      printf("..."); // превышение количества элементов списка
      return(-1);      
    }
  }
  strncpy(pt->id,str,MAXDL);
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: зачем же... это просто функция, которая заменит id в к-том элементе списка, соответственно необходимо передать ей указатель на новый id третьим параметром. Для этого предварительно необходимо считать введенный пользователем id в некоторую строку. Т.е.: 1 параметром - указатель на начало списка, 2-м - порядковый номер элемента, id котрого надо заменить, 3-м - строка с id, на который меняем... как то так

Comment: @margosh, я бы еще pt->id[MAXDL-1] = 0; приписал.

Comment: @avp, определенно :)  
@coddddder, сори, времени на детальный разбор нету, прийдется Вам подумать) Вы ведь читаете какой элемент удалить:  
 
>> printf("nKakou ydalit?:n");
>> scanf("%d", &k);

считайте так же, какой заменить, и на что заменить, передайте это в функцию в качестве парметров.